# Can I consume multiple event hubs with different subscriptions in one program?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I want to consume multiple Azure-EventHub with different subscriptions in one program.
can I create multiple eph new connections with different subscriptions ? and will I be able to consume events from multiple event hubs belongs to different subscriptions parallel ?

Comment: Sure, why not. But why would you?

Comment: @PeterBons There is a requirement in my current project to pull logs from multiple event hubs with different subscriptions and process it . I hope we have to create multiple eph.newconnection objects corresponding to each subscription, does it make sense? Please share your thoughts over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can pull multiple event hub belongs to different subscription in our program parallel , the only thing we need to careful about storage container(for lease checker), as we have to use storage container name for each event hub and container should be in same resource group in which event hub is available.

Comment: how did you manage the SAS keys to access each hub? did your app have granted access to retrieve the keys dynamically?